# How to disable default video controls and show custom seekbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I working with video here I want to hide default video controls using jquery and show my custom seek bar. I tried to like this `controls=false` but if I disable this my custom bar also disable. I want to shoe custom bar and play button. I don't want to use any plugins.
Can anyone suggest me the right way?

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("video");
vid.ontimeupdate = function(){
  var percentage = ( vid.currentTime / vid.duration ) * 100;
  $("#custom-seekbar span").css("width", percentage+"%");
};

$("#custom-seekbar").on("click", function(e){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var left = (e.pageX - offset.left);
    var totalWidth = $("#custom-seekbar").width();
    var percentage = ( left / totalWidth );
    var vidTime = vid.duration * percentage;
    vid.currentTime = vidTime;
});//click()
```

```css
#custom-seekbar
{  
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  outline: thin solid orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}
#custom-seekbar span
{
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0px;
}

/* following rule is for hiding Stack Overflow's console  */
.as-console-wrapper{ display: none !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="custom-seekbar">
  <span></span>
</div>
<video id="video" width="400" controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because you have not defined the `percentage` variable in general section. See the code snippet below:

```js
var percentage = 0;

video.ontimeupdate = function(){
  percentage = ( video.currentTime / video.duration ) * 100;
  $( '#custom-seekbar span' ).css( 'width', percentage + '%' )
}

$( '#custom-seekbar' ).on( 'click', function( e ){
  var offset = $( this ).offset(),
      left = ( e.pageX - offset.left ),
      totalWidth = $( '#custom-seekbar' ).width(),
      percentage = ( left / totalWidth );

  video.currentTime = video.duration * percentage;
})
```

```css
#custom-seekbar {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 400px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: thin solid orange;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px
}
#custom-seekbar span {
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.2s
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="custom-seekbar">
    <span></span>
</div>
<video id="video" width="400" autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

**Update:** Add Play, Pause and Repeat buttons.

```js
var percentage = 0;

video.ontimeupdate = function(){
  percentage = ( video.currentTime / video.duration ) * 100;
  $( '#custom-seekbar span' ).css( 'width', percentage + '%' );

  if ( percentage >= 100 ) $( '#play_button' ).html( '⥀' ) /* Repeat */
}

$( '#custom-seekbar' ).on( 'click', function( e ){
  var offset = $( this ).offset(),
      left = ( e.pageX - offset.left ),
      totalWidth = $( this ).width(),
      percentage = ( left / totalWidth );

  video.currentTime = video.duration * percentage;
})

$( '#play_button' ).on( 'click', function() {
  if ( video.paused ) {
    video.play();
    $( this ).html( '&#10074;&#10074;' ) /* Pause */
  } else {
    video.pause();
    $( this ).html( '&#9658;' ) /* Play */
  }
} )
```

```css
.player {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto
}
#video {
    width: 100%
}
#custom-seekbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 7px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
#custom-seekbar span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 7px;
  width: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .8);
  transition-duration: 0.2s
}
#play_button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  left: 6px;
  top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, .8);
  border: none;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition-duration: 0.3s
}
#play_button:hover,
#custom-seekbar:hover span {
    background-color: #ff8605
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="player">
  <video id="video">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div id="custom-seekbar">
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="play_button" title="Play / Pause">&#9658;</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I want using simple js you achieve it.

Comment: How did you write restart symbol?